# PHP make install seems to end abruptly and does not update libphp5.so

Tags: linux, php, redhat, 64-bit, make

I'm trying to compile PHP 5.3.3 and after a lot of ups and downs, I finally did 'make' it followed by 'make install' which just shows this:

```
root@server [/tmp/php-5.3.3]# make install
Installing PHP SAPI module:       cgi
Installing PHP CGI binary: /usr/bin/
Installing PHP CLI binary:        /usr/bin/
Installing PHP CLI man page:      /usr/share/man/man1/
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib64/20090626/
Installing build environment:     /usr/lib64/build/
Installing header files:          /usr/include/php/
Installing helper programs:       /usr/bin/
  program: phpize
  program: php-config
Installing man pages:             /usr/share/man/man1/
  page: phpize.1
  page: php-config.1
/tmp/php-5.3.3/build/shtool install -c ext/phar/phar.phar /usr/bin
ln -s -f /usr/bin/phar.phar /usr/bin/phar
Installing PDO headers:          /usr/include/php/ext/pdo/
```

It does not look like its done, because /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so still shows an old date:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3193768 Mar 31  2010 libphp5.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need build apache2handler:

```
$./configure --with-apxs2
```

Then clean build directory and build php:

```
$make clean
$make
$make install
```

Read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Comment: Didnt' quite work - said "Sorry, I cannot run apxs.  Possible reasons follow:

1. Perl is not installed
2. apxs was not found. Try to pass the path using --with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs
3. Apache was not built using --enable-so (the apxs usage page is displayed)"

Comment: Where / how can I download this apxs module? Please dont tell me that I have to make/compile apache as well!!

Comment: install httpd-dev

Answer (score 1):

In the ./configure of php is possible that you select a prefix, but it is not necessary and you can compile with only `./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it didn't update mod_php. You told it to build cgi instead.

Comment: Did I?? I took the ./configure options from what PHP 5.1.6 "Configure Command" showed me in phpinfo() before upgrading.

Comment: Well, your output above reads "cgi".

Comment: You're right - trying to work on the  --with-apxs2 option...